# mysql update query (with prepared statements) not working

Tags: c#, mysql, database, syntax-error, prepared-statement

I'm stuck trying to figure out why a MySQL UPDATE query won't update a MySQL database via a c# windows form. I am using prepared statements with placeholders for security and I am getting an error message about a syntax problem that i'm stuck on. The information I have found on this site pertains to incorporating prepared statements with php/mysql, and msqli so the solutions don't fit my problem.

This is the table I am trying to update
CREATE TABLE job (

```
job_code VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
job_title VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
    job_last_update DATE NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (job_code)

)ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is my c# code for the button the user clicks to update the database

```
    private void btnUpdateJobsTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        String myConnection = @"server=localhost; database=beautyshopdb; username=*******; password=*****; convert zero datetime=True";
        MySqlConnection Connect = null;
        try
        {

            Connect = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            Connect.Open(); //open the connection
            //This is the mysql command that we will query into the db.
            //It uses Prepared statements and the Placeholder is @name.
            //Using prepared statements is faster and secure.
            //String updateQuery = "UPDATE job(job_code, job_title, job_last_update) VALUES(@jobCode, @jobTitle, @lastUpdated)";

            String updateQuery = "UPDATE job SET job_title = @jobTitle +, job_last_update = @lastUpdated WHERE job_code = @jobCode";

            MySqlCommand cmdInsertJobsToDataBase = new MySqlCommand(updateQuery, Connect);
            cmdInsertJobsToDataBase.Prepare();
            //we will bound a value to the placeholder
            cmdInsertJobsToDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobCode", this.txtEnterJobCode.Text);
            cmdInsertJobsToDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobTitle", this.txtEnterJobTitle.Text);
            cmdInsertJobsToDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastUpdated", this.dateTimePickerJobLastUpdated.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            cmdInsertJobsToDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery(); //execute the mysql command
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (Connect != null)
            {
                Connect.Close(); //close the connection
            }
            autoLoadDataBaseTables();//auto refresh/load datagrid for Jobs table when user clicks on 'Save' button
            //fillComboBoxOnEmployeePage(); //auto load job code data into employee form

            //Clear all textbox fields and reset TimeDatePicker to system date after data is saved
            this.txtEnterJobCode.Text = String.Empty;
            this.txtEnterJobTitle.Text = String.Empty;

            //Inform user that tranaction was successfull
            lblErrorProviderMessage_Success.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

This is my error message

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'job_last_update = '01/05/2014' WHERE job_code = "UPDATE" at line
>   one

Can someone please help understand what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

First problem in your code is `+` in Statement

```
String updateQuery = "UPDATE job SET job_title = @jobTitle +, job_last_update = @lastUpdated WHERE job_code = @jobCode";
                                                      //^^^^^^
```

Just remove it

```
String updateQuery = "UPDATE job SET job_title = @jobTitle , job_last_update = @lastUpdated WHERE job_code = @jobCode";
```

Your `job_last_update` is be of type `Date` in Database, and you are passing a formatted string from your query. Just remove the `ToString` and pass the `DateTime` object directly.

```
cmdInsertJobsToDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastUpdated", 
                                 this.dateTimePickerJobLastUpdated.Value);
```

If you only want to send the `Date` Part, then use `DateTime.Date` property which will have time set to `00:00:00`. In that case use:

```
cmdInsertJobsToDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastUpdated", 
                                 this.dateTimePickerJobLastUpdated.Value.Date);
```

Comment: Hello Habib: Before I put up this post, tried your first suggestion and it didn't work. I just tried your second tip and no luck. The database is not updating. , but the information still won't post to the dabase.

Comment: Error message when i use the first tip :check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'job_last_update = '2014-05-01 00:00:00' WHERE job_code = "UPDATE" at line 1

Comment: @user3629850, are you sure you are not using `ToString` because it appears that the Date is passed in single quotes

Comment: Error message when I used the 2nd tip (.value.Date): check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'job_last_update = '2014-05-01 16:12:47' WHERE job_code = "UPDATE" at line one

Comment: No i'm definitely not using ToString. I used .Value and then I tried .Value.Date. This is so maddening, lol

Comment: @user3629850, I would **never** recommend that but try `cmdInsertJobsToDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastUpdated", this.dateTimePickerJobLastUpdated.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));`

Comment: @user3629850, you have **+** in your UPDATE statement, A Typo, remove that, that is causing the issues, but you should pass your `Date` as I have explained in my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much Habib. I removed the typo (+) and the application works perfectly. Couldn't have figured that out without you!